# C# WPF CanExecuteChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, button, canexecute

I have created a CustomControl which extends TextBox.
Within my control I have added a button:

AppTextBox.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ButtonCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(AppTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnButtonCommandChanged));

    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value);
    }

private static void OnButtonCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is AppTextBox atb)
        {
            atb.ButtonCommand = (ICommand)e.NewValue;
            atb.SetButtonIsActive(atb);
        }
    }
```

This is how I setup the TextBox:

```
<ctrl:AppTextBox ButtonCommand="{Binding AddSpokenFormCommand}"
                 ButtonLabel="+"
                 Label="Spoken Form"
                 Text="{Binding SpokenFormText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                 x:Name="txtSpokenForm" />
```

Within my ViewModel I have the following:

```
public RelayCommand AddSpokenFormCommand { get; }

AddSpokenFormCommand = new(OnAddSpokenFormCommand, AddSpokenFormCommandCanExecute);

private bool AddSpokenFormCommandCanExecute() => SpokenFormText.Length != 0;
```

The issue I am facing is that the CustomControl is not always set to the correct state.

I have a listbox where I can select an entry, when the entry loads the CustomControl seems to keep the state it was in from the last record.

CustomControl when first loaded: (This is in the correct state)
[image: Initial]

CustomControl when text added: (This is in the correct state)
[image: With Text]

CustomControl when moved to next record: (as you can see there is no text, but the button is active (and it shouldnt be))
[image: Next Record]

How can I force the UI to refresh based on the data that it now holds after reloading?

Comment: As a note, the assignment `atb.ButtonCommand = (ICommand)e.NewValue` in `OnButtonCommandChanged` is redundant. The property already has that value when the PropertyChangedCallback is called. The call `atb.SetButtonIsActive(atb)` looks also odd. Why pass the reference to the class instance as method argument when you call an instance method (as opposed to a (static) class method)?

Comment: I thought I had to do it in that way to ensure it was setting the correct object. Maybe this is part of the issue.
What I found was if I set them OnxChanged methods, the UI in the designer was actually being updated in real time

Comment: The SetButtonIsActive method might perhaps be the problem.

Comment: You were right, it was something in either the atb. or the atb.ButtonCommand = (ICommand)e.NewValue. 

I have updated my control to now not have atb. and everything seems to work correctly. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setup in AppTextBox.cs was causing the issues.

Because the class has instance methods, there is no need to pass around a reference.

Once I removed all of the atb.*x* then the control behaved as it should do.

*Thanks to Clemens for the pointers*